# Apostrophecms : How to add url params in url by slashesh

Tags: url-parameters, apostrophe-cms, url-pattern

When I am trying to add params like `localhost:8080/one/two`,apostrophe is considering this as a slug and gives 404 error.

Whereas adding params like `localhost:8080/?one=one&two=two` is working fine but I want like `localhost:8080/one/two`. How should I manage this?

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an `apostrophe-custom-pages` module to own your homepage route `/` and then you can add routes to it by defining them with the `dispatch` method.

There is a pretty good overview and example of this in the How Apostrophe Handles Requests overview

https://apostrophecms.org/docs/technical-overviews/how-apostrophe-handles-requests.html